# Custom Delegate in UINavigationController calling from subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I have a UINavigationController which is presented in a Modal view. I want the view which is presenting the navigationcontroller to be responsible for removing the modal. Therefor I created a delegate method on the UINavigationController:

```
@protocol MyNaviDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)userWantsToQuit;

@end
```

How can I call this delegate method from a subview (lets say if the user is 2 levels deep into the navigationcontroller (like VIEW C)?

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| NAVIGATION CONTROLLER                                 |
| --------------     --------------      -------------- |
| |  VIEW A    |  -> |   VIEW B   |  ->  |   VIEW C   | |
| |            |     |            |      |            | |
| --------------     --------------      -------------- |
|                                                       |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a view controller for each view ?

Comment: I think you have to create another delegate for view C and set viewC.delegate = UINavigationController instance.

Comment: setting delegate in UIView subclasses is not recommended design-wise. Thats part of the view controller job to manage its view's actions. The view should not care who presented it or who shall dismiss it.

Comment: @giorashc yes every view has is own viewcontroller, which is pushed via the navigationcontroller...

Comment: can you post the code on how you push your views ?

Comment: I use segues to push to the new viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You can send Notification on a particular event(from View C) to that controller class in which you are presenting the navigationcontroller. Then you can remove it.

Comment: I know but I was wondering if I could use delegates for this. Notifications are ok, but I rather use delegates...

Comment: You can use delegates, but with multiple controllers between your presented view and your nav controller, the simplest way is to use notifications.  Otherwise, just put a delegate in every VC and call back til you hit the Nav controller.